# How to pass data from delete method to api route in new next13 app dir?

Tags: node.js, next.js, axios, server-side-rendering

I use the new next13 app dir, I want to pass some data from the delete method (DeleteShipment) using Axios to API route (/api/shipments/[shipmentsId]/route.ts).

```js
(DeleteShipment.tsx):
const shipmentData = {
  "id": "644435b27fd6c9d3b2c4cfb7",
  "createdAt": "2023-04-22T19:29:54.111Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-04-22T19:29:54.111Z",
  "userId": "643ad685a3aa5f2976c7cbfd"}

await axios.delete(`/api/shipments/${shipmentId}`,
 {data: shipmentData});


(/api/shipments/[shipmentsId]/route.ts):
export async function DELETE(req: Request) {
// get shipmentData
shipmentData= ??
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the way you sent the data is correct. that `data` is attached to `req.body`. so in your api function

```
const shipmentData= req.body
```

From the docs

> `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
> Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'

Comment: thanks, i tried that before but i cannot complete it! how to get shipmentData.id from that?

Comment: if u `console.log(shipmentData)` on handler, what is logged on terminal console?

Comment: {
  data: {
    id: '64453ce16fc3a120ca181841',
    userId: '643ad685a3aa5f2976c7cbfd',
    shipmentId: '64453ce16fc3a120ca181840',
   ...
  }
}

Comment: `const id=shipmentData?.data?.id`. then `console.log(id)`

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>'.

Comment: how to fix that?

Comment: what is next.js version?

Comment: "next": "13.3.1", "typescript": "5.0.4"

Comment: you successfully log the id, right?

Comment: no, it give me an error with (data?)

Comment: `const shipmentData= JSON.parse(req.body)` can u try this

Comment: Argument of type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 0):

Try to await it:

```
const body = await req.json()
const { shipmentData } = body
```

UPDATE:

I'll share my full DELETE request function:

```
// DELETE
export async function DELETE(req: NextRequest) {

  const body = await req.json()
  const { id } = body

  return NextResponse.json({}, { status: 200 });

}
```

and my fetch request looks like this, for your reference:

```
const options:any = {
      method: 'DELETE',
      body: JSON.stringify({id})
    }
    const res = await fetch(`/YOUR_API_ROUTE_PATH`, options)
    const deleted = await res.json()
```